# WPF equivalent to GDI+'s ColorMatrix

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, gdi+, colormatrix

I noticed that WPF has the System.Windows.Media(.Imaging) namespaces that contain a lot of the same functionality as System.Drawing(.Imagine), but I don't see an equivalent to the ColorMatrix in GDI+. I actually don't see a way of doing color transformations in general. Does one exist? I'm happy using GDI+ but was just curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WPF allows you to write custom pixel shaders. These are more versatile than a ColorMatrix which you could replicate as a pixel shader, plus they are executed on the GPU. [Shazzam](http://shazzam-tool.com/) ships with some samples and simplifies the process of writing them.

*Just to note: WPF is more suited for creating user interfaces than image editing, there's not much more than the members of [System.Windows.Media.Imaging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.aspx) like WriteableBitmap and RenderTargetBitmap. If you are after bitmap image editing features gdi+ and Direct2D might be more appropriate.*

Comment: Regarding your WPF relevance comment: that is what I figured, I just wanted to make sure since I'm completely new to image editing. This is probably a stupid question but are the pixel shaders faster to execute that using GDI+/ColorMatrix?

Comment: PixelShader will run significantly faster on PS capable GPU. Otherwise it will run in software mode imho comparable to GDI+. Hard to tell without measuring it.

Comment: They should be significantly faster as they are executed on the GPU. RenderTargetBitmap uses slower software rendering but you would only use that when you save the result, it would be very fast whilst changing the properties of the shader. I didn't want to deter you from WPF just that its bitmap editing features are limited.

Comment: Using HLSL actually looks pretty compelling. I'm not using either GDI or WPF for UI, so I'm only concerned with which provides the best mechanism for image editing. GDI/ColorMatrix seems better than System.Windows.Media.Imaging, but I'm intruiged by WPF's PixelShader. Does Direct2D use HLSL as well?

Comment: I haven't used Direct2D, initially I mentioned it as it allows drawing shapes e.t.c directly to a image wheras WPF is a retained mode API. From a quick look at msdn it doesn't seem offer something like ColorMatrix, you would need to use direct3d to use HLSL. You might be interested in http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.formatconvertedbitmap.aspx?

Edit: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.effects.pixelshader.aspx, but i think it is not best answer because you must know about HLSL.

Comment: That seems to provide a set number of transformations (e.g. doing grey-scale), but doesn't allow you to do arbitrary bitmap transformation from what I can tell.